# com.liferay.portal.kernel.xml.DocumentException: Error on line -1 of document : Premature end of file

Tags: xml, liferay

i'm trying to use Liferay and i got this error , i know the problem is in XML file, but i'm not able to understand in WHICH FILE it is, saw similar question but i think this is different cause it refers on Liferay framework,

```
`08:24:54,239 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][HotDeployImpl:233] com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error registering portlets for guestbook-portletguestbook-portlet
com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error registering portlets for guestbook-portletguestbook-portlet
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.BaseHotDeployListener.throwHotDeployException(BaseHotDeployListener.java:46)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:128)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:230)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:257)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:28)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:164)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:154)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:44)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:58)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:54)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1263)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1948)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.xml.DocumentException: Error on line -1 of document  : Premature end of file. Nested exception: Premature end of file.
    at com.liferay.portal.xml.SAXReaderImpl.read(SAXReaderImpl.java:396)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.xml.UnsecureSAXReaderUtil.read(UnsecureSAXReaderUtil.java:54)
    at com.liferay.portal.security.permission.ResourceActionsImpl.read(ResourceActionsImpl.java:625)
    at com.liferay.portal.security.permission.ResourceActionsUtil.read(ResourceActionsUtil.java:275)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.processPortletProperties(PortletHotDeployListener.java:690)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:441)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:125)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line -1 of document  : Premature end of file. Nested exception: Premature end of file.
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:343)
    at com.liferay.portal.xml.SAXReaderImpl.read(SAXReaderImpl.java:393)
    ... 30 more`
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: my code is pretty huge, if u tell me which file you want to see, glad to post it

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jww as i told in my question, i'm not able to understand from log in whuch file the error is, otherwise i would be able to past the code, minimal, complete and verifible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using 6.2 GA6. There's this line in your stacktrace

```
at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.processPortletProperties(PortletHotDeployListener.java:690)
```

that points to [this code](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.5-ga6/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/deploy/hot/PortletHotDeployListener.java#L690), suggesting it's the permissions declaration, e.g. `resource-actions/default.xml`

If that's not your version, please use the appropriate tag in github and look up what other file is being read in that line in your version.

Comment: thx a lot, this is the exact answer i needed to point the problem